# Could not load type 'Ninject.Web.WebApi.IWebApiRequestScopeProvider' from assembly 'Ninject.Web.WebApi'

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I've recently upgraded my solution to .net Framework 4.8 and updated a load of nuget packages and now I'm having problems getting my API project to launch.

I felt this smelled of bad binding redirect, but I've looked at this and they are as follows...

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Ninject" publicKeyToken="c7192dc5380945e7" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.3.4.0" newVersion="3.3.4.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Ninject.Web.Common" publicKeyToken="c7192dc5380945e7" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.3.2.0" newVersion="3.3.2.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Ninject.Web.Common.OwinHost" publicKeyToken="c7192dc5380945e7" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.3.1.0" newVersion="3.3.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Ninject.Web.WebApi" publicKeyToken="c7192dc5380945e7" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.3.1.0" newVersion="3.3.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

And here's the packages.config...

```
  <package id="Ninject" version="3.3.4" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Ninject.Extensions.NamedScope" version="3.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Ninject.Web.Common" version="3.3.2" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Ninject.Web.Common.OwinHost" version="3.3.1" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost" version="3.3.2" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Ninject.Web.WebApi" version="3.3.1" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Ninject.Web.WebApi.OwinHost" version="3.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
```

There's no specific redirect here for `Ninject.Web.WebApi.OwinHost` so I'm thinking that may be the issue or maybe one of the other libraries, but they never had redirects before and I've tried...

```
Get-Package MyApp.Api | Add-Bindings
```

(excuse the syntax here - it may be wrong as from memory)

...to add relevant bindings that were missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was caused by a versioning issue with Nuget packages (This is why I don't use Ninject by choice anymore...)

I downgraded the WebApi package as follows...

```
<package id="Ninject.Web.WebApi" version="3.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
```

So that it was in line with `Ninject.Web.WebApi.OwinHost`, cleaned, rebuilt and tried again and it all worked perfectly.

I would suspect that the `Ninject.Web.WebApi.OwinHost` package hasn't been updated yet and isn't compatible.

Comment: This did in fact fix the issue for me as well, so thank you. For anyone else reading this in the future, make sure to check your binding redirects as well; if you are redirecting to 3.3.1 then downgrading the package will not have an effect.

Comment: What do you use in place of Ninject?  I love Ninject but it doesn't seem as active as it once was so I've been looking for alternatives.

Comment: @HiredMind - [OPINION WARNING] I find the built in DI is more than sufficient in .net core projects and AutoFac is my go to outside of that - Neither use 'magic' concepts to do everything for you so you have far better understanding of how your bindings are working (each to their own!).

Answer (score 2):

The package

```
<package id="Ninject.Web.WebApi.OwinHost" version="3.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
```

was replaced by

```
<package id="Ninject.Web.WebApi.OwinSelfHost" version="3.3.1" targetFramework="net48" />
```

https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.WebApi/issues/32#issuecomment-661886853

In my case I also needed to update Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin to version 5.2.7.